# Combine 3 separate working scripts - for drupal computed field

Tags: php, drupal

I'm using computed field in drupal, which uses just straight up PHP, only problem is I don't know php well.

The 3 scripts below, work individually.  When I try to combine them, using different syntax of course, they all fail. What I'm trying to do is add up 3 fields, from 3 different field sets or field collections.

1st

```
$price = 0;
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $entity);
foreach($wrapper->field_venue_sites_simple as $collection) {
   $price += $collection->field_site_fee->value();
}
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $price;
```

2nd

```
$price = 0;
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $entity);
foreach($wrapper->field_venue_sites_w_catering as $collection) {
   $price += $collection->field_site_fee->value();
}
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $price;
```

3rd

```
$price = 0;
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $entity);
foreach($wrapper->field_venue_site as $collection) {
   $price += $collection->field_peak_pricing->field_peak_price_saturday->value();
}
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $price;
```

I've tried this to combine them, but it doesn't work:

```
$price = 0;
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $entity);

$price = 

$wrapper->field_venue_sites_simple->field_site_fee->value() +
$wrapper->field_venue_site->field_peak_pricing->field_peak_price_saturday->value() +
$wrapper->field_venue_sites_w_catering->field_site_fee->value();

$entity_field[0]['value'] = $price;
```

I've aware the foreach loops through arrays.  I don't need it to loop, so I can take that out.  They are all multiple value fields, but I only need it to pull one value.

I've also tried this, and it didn't not work either:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $entity);

$collection1 = $wrapper->field_venue_sites_simple;
$collection2 = $wrapper->field_venue_site;
$collection3 = $wrapper->field_venue_sites_w_catering;


$entity_field[0]['value'] =
$collection1->field_site_fee->value()+
$collection2->field_peak_pricing->field_peak_price_saturday->value()+
$collection3->field_site_fee->value();
```

Any help greatly appreciated!  Been messing with this all day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just combine the parts where the three examples differ…

```
$price = 0;
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $entity);
foreach($wrapper->field_venue_sites_simple as $collection) {
  $price += $collection->field_site_fee->value();
}  
foreach($wrapper->field_venue_sites_w_catering as $collection) {
  $price += $collection->field_site_fee->value(); 
}
foreach($wrapper->field_venue_site as $collection) {
  $price += $collection->field_peak_pricing->field_peak_price_saturday->value();
}

$entity_field[0]['value'] = $price;
```

Comment: That works.  Thanks so much.  I knew one of you smart guys would be able to do it in minutes!